# Adding UINavigation bar programmatically

Tags: ios

I was trying to add the navigation bar to the application programmatically but I didn't got any success.

I had tried the code mentioned below

```
UIBarButtonItem *alefttbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Setting"   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(settingAction:)];

alefttbarButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
alefttbarButton.tintColor= [UIColor redColor];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=alefttbarButton;
self.navigationController.delegate=self;
self.title =@"test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. In this particular case I created my views all by hand. Starting in the applicationDidFinishLaunching, I have the following code:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
mainCtl = [[MainController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:mainCtl.nav.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

As you can see I here allocate and initialize an instance of MainController, which is a subclass of UIViewController.
Then, in the initialization of this MainController I have a call to the navigation bar initialization code:

```
[self initNavBar];
```

which is the following function:

```
- (void) initNavBar
{
    printf("initNavBar entered\n");
    self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self];

    //setup the middle view
    int btnCount = 4;
    CGRect buttonsFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btnCount*BUTTONWIDTH + (btnCount-1)*BUTTONSPACING + 2*BUTTONMARGIN, BUTTONHEIGHT + 2*BUTTONMARGIN);
    UIView *buttonsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:buttonsFrame];
    UIButton *button;
    CGFloat left = BUTTONMARGIN;

    // create button for photo selector invocation
    button = [self buttonWithName:@"photo" target:self selector:@selector(showImagePicker) left:left];
    //button = [self createButton:@"photo" action:@selector(showImagePicker) left:left];
    [buttonsView addSubview:button];

    left += (BUTTONWIDTH+BUTTONSPACING);
    button = [self buttonWithName:@"crop" target:self selector:@selector(cropImage) left:left];
    [buttonsView addSubview: button];

    left += (BUTTONWIDTH+BUTTONSPACING);
    kissButton = [self buttonWithName:@"kiss" target:self selector:@selector(cropImage) left:left];
    [buttonsView addSubview: kissButton];

    //left += (BUTTONWIDTH+BUTTONSPACING);
    left += (BUTTONWIDTH+BUTTONSPACING);
    button = [self buttonWithName:@"mail" target:self selector:@selector(showMailDialog) left:left];
    //button = [self createButton:@"mail" action:@selector(showMailDialog) left:left];
    [buttonsView addSubview:button];
    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    //only enable the mail button if the class exists
    button.enabled = (mailClass != nil);

    printf("initNavBar done\n");
}
```

This is all working code. If you can look through the cruft you'll manage to get the picture.
Hope this helps.